# Angular 8 application ignoring Content Security policy from Http request

Tags: angular, xss, content-security-policy

In an Angular 8 application, we are trying to apply the CSP policies to it from HTTP request.

API returning data contains following csp directive.

```
img-src https://i.imgur.com data: 'self';
```

But when we load the page which contains image from different domain, it loads. Ideally it is violate the Content security policy and doesn't load the image.
What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> API returning data contains following csp directive.
>
> ```
> img-src https://i.imgur.com data: 'self';
> ```

If you'll set by JavaScript the `<meta http-equiv="Content Security Policy" content="img-src https://i.imgur.com data: 'self';">` with the data from your API, it prevent loading images from different domains.

**But:**

- you can do in only once at loaded page, any removing/modifying this meta tag could just make this CSP stricter. Actually it will be always added additional meta tags and you'll have a myltiple CSP.You can remove meta tag from DOM, but not from the internal slot where browser keeps it.
- tag added by JavaScript affects only resources will start loading AFTER meta been set. All started BEFORE will loaded.